# Windows Named Pipe Client in Overlapped mode

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes, overlapped-io

I am using Named Pipes to communicate between two processes running in Windows. This is implemented in c++ using the Win32 API. The server pipe is implemented asynchronously using an overlapped structure. Can the same can be implemented on the client side, when reading?

Any examples I have seen on Asynchronous pipe communications refers to the server side and I know that a ReadFile operation has an overlapped option, however this does not necessarily mean that this will work for named pipes because ReadFile has many uses.

Could someone advise please?

Comment: of course client also can use asynchronous I/O. ReadFile support asynchronous I/O with for iocp and event . ReadFileEx - for apc. NtReadFile for all

Comment: Thanks. I got this working. I just wasn't sure because I couldn't find any examples, or mention of asynchronous named pipe clients.

Comment: No any difference between client and server here. Both can use synchronous or asynchronous io from self side.